# Into what type of animal did David transform the woman?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lobster

At one point in [The Lobster](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3464902/fullcredits/), the narrator explains that the protagonist David transforms a woman into an animal. The narrator also says that David wouldn't disclose what type of animal he chose the woman to be.

Is there any clue in the movie as to what type of animal the woman became?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's a rabbit.

Rabbits are helpless animals, destined to brutal death by human or predator. People probably don't often willingly choose to become one. It would also be in opposition to Cruel Woman's nature - she was controlling and a good hunter. As a rabbit, she would become the hunted one.

But more importantly, David's later girlfriend loves to eat rabbits. So that's why he won't tell her.

Comment: +1 and answer accepted - this makes sense, especially the part about why he won't tell his later girlfriend. Thank you!

Comment: @fade_out This response seems ***oddly similar*** to the highest rated reddit response regarding the same topic. https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueFilm/comments/4s2sc3/two_questions_about_the_lobster_both_concerning/

Comment: I have to disagree with the rationale here. It's possible she was turned into a rabbit, but there's nothing in particular to indicate this. If there appeared only a single rabbit in the film, it would be a clearer indication, but there are multiple rabbits and there's no correlation between when they discussed the lady and the hunting of rabbits. Yes the rabbit being the weak creature is an obvious choice, but it's equally as likely to be a creature of which there is only one, such as the camel or the peacock, seeing as how the lady was singled out for being heartless.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe that she has become a cat in the film. The first point of consideration would be what is the most common animal that people chose. That is of course the dog. What is the purpose or intent that the film  maker has to place certain animals in the film. There is a camel used as a punchline, a dog the most common animal in the and is the brother to the films main antagonist. A horse being the transformation of the nose bleed woman's best friends main idea being converted over. The ass at the start of the film bringing us into the concept of the film. There are several others within that I do not cover but do have their own purpose. One other that I will cover is the short cameo of a cat in the forest. This cat would be the biggest outsider due to the large majority of dogs that inhabit the place. This inturn would drive david to turn the heartless women into a cat for a complete switch of power for her and life that would have the people she made not run or were court away due to fear turn on her or have in one way or another be somewhat come round to bite her on the ass.

Answer (score 0):

My unique belief is that the whole concept of turning people into other animals was a sham for illegal organ harvesting.

Remember in one scene the blood goes to a nearby hospital and the organs are removed from the body and the body tossed. Please note Farrell refused to say what animal he turned the evil woman into (I mean really, how could he do it without having some incredible knowledge, all he likely saw was a morgue or operating room for harvesting). He knew what it was but didn't want to scare others for other reasons.

In the director's other films he takes bizarre situations that could absolutely occur in the real world. Why would this be any different? IMHO most people I think just skimmed the story and missed every single plot point.

Comment: Or maybe the story _is_ absurd and _you_ missed the whole plot. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

David is an odd fella. That being said the animal he wanted to be turned into was a lobster. Meaning he knows about sea creatures.

Before bringing her to the transformation room, the narrarator states that he wanted to kick her in the stomach and then stab her but didn't because she wouldn't feel any of it being tranqualized.

He turned her into a [sea louse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_louse). The female sea louse is abducted by the male, then graped, graped by having her stomach punctured by the male. She will then be impregnated and while the babies mature inside of her they EAT HER ALIVE.
So yeah. This would be the kind of revenge he would love for her to get.